# Autolayout: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Symbolic breakpoint does not show the error message

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I ran to the issue and I cannot get my head around how to solve this. I have four views, each with elements inside has its constraints, you can see the full list in the picture below. [image]
[image]

When I run the app, and click on the any one of the text fields, nothing happens and works just fine. However, when I click on the other text field I get this not very pleasant error message.

[image]

Well, I followed the steps, and added a symbolic breakpoint, but it did not give any useful information, as you can see below,

[image]

I have been stuck on this for a while, and tried many things, including changing the priorities of both views and textfields, as well as deleting some of the constraints that might have caused the problem. Unfortunately, nothing works :( Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The TUISystemInputAssistantView mentioned by the console message is *not your view*. Ignore the message (and file a bug report with Apple). It's not your problem.